# String substitution - unsupported format character '}'

Tags: javascript, python, html, google-app-engine

I'm trying to do some string substitution for html/javascript templating, however when the page string variable has a curly brace in the code, I get the error of "ValueError: unsupported format character '}' (0x7d)". If I don't have any string substitution everything works fine. Thanks for reading!

```
import webapp2
page = """
<html>
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    %(say)s
</html>
    """

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write_form(self, say):
        self.response.out.write(page % { "say": say })

    def get(self):
        self.write_form("hello")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)],
                              debug=True)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your 'template' contains the string `% }` (right after the `100` there), and python is interpreting that as a formatting instruction.

Double the `%` percent characters to `%%` and it'll work.

```
>>> page = """
... <html>
...     <style type="text/css">
...       html { height: 100%% }
...       body { height: 100%%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
...       #map_canvas { height: 100%% }
...     </style>
...     %(say)s
... </html>
...     """
>>> page % dict(say='foo')
'\n<html>\n    <style type="text/css">\n      html { height: 100% }\n      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }\n      #map_canvas { height: 100% }\n    </style>\n    foo\n</html>\n    '
```

Alternatively, use the newer [`.format()` method](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings) for a format less prone to such problems, although in this specific case that'll get hung up on the `{ height: 100% }` curly braces pairs, so your mileage may very well vary; you'd have to double those instead (so `{{ height: 100% }}`).